# CakePHP Homepage URL Redirect

Tags: php, cakephp

My website is using CakePHP and homepage URL gets redirected and looks like this

```
domain.com/pages/home
```

I want to prevent the redirect load index file at `domain.com` I can't figure out how to load index without redirecting.

This is what I have right now.

```
    if(!$this->Auth->loggedIn()){
        return $this->redirect('/pages/home');
    }
```

Comment: Are you talking about Routing ? https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html

Comment: I tried routing but I wasn't able to get it to work. `Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home'));` and this in the controller   `if(!$this->Auth->loggedIn()){
   $this->home();
  }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check in routes.php file if you have this line of code (if not add it).

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home'));
```

and this in the controller

```
if(!$this->Auth->loggedIn()){ 

    $this->redirect('/');
    //or
    //$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home'));

}
```

Comment: I tried it, spits out google chrome error "This Page Isn't Working"

Comment: in which controller function you added redirect code ?

Comment: PagesController, SignedIn function

Comment: can you post the code available in SignedIn and home functions ?

Comment: `public function SignedIn(){
  if(!$this->Auth->loggedIn()){
   $this->redirect('/');
  } $this->loadModel('Post'); .... }`

Comment: I had a duplicated router for '/' that's why it wasn't working. Thank you for the help!